# R grid does not start at 0,0 on the plot

Tags: r

I'm creating a plot and trying to add a grid:

```
plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(0, 10), ylim=c(0, 10))
axis(1, at= 0:10)
axis(2, at= 0:10)
grid(10, 10, col = 'black')
```

However, the grid is not starting at 0,0 on the plot:
[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: See `xaxs` and `yaxs` argument of `plot` (`?par`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use argument `xaxs` and `yaxs` in `plot` function. You can get more detail in `?par`.

```
plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(0, 10), ylim=c(0, 10), xaxs="i", yaxs="i")
axis(1, at= 0:10)
axis(2, at= 0:10)
grid(10, 10, col = 'black')
```

[image]